# php get word between two different tags

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am parsing a website using `DOMDocument` class.

The html code is like this

```
<img src="xxxxxx">
abc
<br>
<img src="xxxxxx">
def
<br>
.....
```

What I want is to extract the img src link and the words between `<img>` tag and `<br>` tag as a pair. I am looping to get all the pairs inside the html code.

I am able to get all `<img>` src using `getElementsByTagName` but I have no idea how can I get those words between img and br tag.

Is there any method to pair those img src and the words?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target the text after, then just get each img tags.

Then after that point it to the next sibling:

```
->nextSibling
```

Rough example:

```
$sample_html = '
<img src="http://www.whatever.com" alt="" />
abc
<br>
<img src="http://goingnowhere.com" alt="">
def
<br>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($sample_html);

$data = array();
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $data[] = array(
        'src' => $image->getAttribute('src'),
        'text' => trim($image->nextSibling->textContent),
    );
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Now this should look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [src] => http://www.whatever.com
        [text] => abc
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [src] => http://goingnowhere.com
        [text] => def
    )

)
```